# Javascript & JQuery Troubles - Grabbing & Writing YouTube Data to Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, wordpress

I would say I have a little experience with Javascript and JQuery, but in the time spent working on one of my newer sites, nothing is going my way. Basically, I use PHP to write a video ID to javascript code, which then executes to get a YouTube video's title, uploader, views, and length. Everything is working fine on my other site ('Latest Videos' sidebar on Mechabyte.com) but on my newer one, FirstPersonTheater.net, nothing works. I've included the JQuery library, but my scripts aren't writing the information to each post's div fields. I've rationalized that this could simply be an effect of using a barebones theme (I'm building my own, but want to get the kinks worked out as I build it), but since I have all the requirements (JQuery library in header + scripts) I think it *should* still work. Here's a peek at my source code, you can also visit [the site](http://firstpersontheater.net) and inspect some of the elements to see if I'm missing anything.

Basic layout (Assume video ID is 0000000000000:

```
<div class="index_post">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
   <div class="image">
      <div class="container" style="background:url('http://img.youtube.com/vi/0000000000000/0.jpg');">
                                                                                                </div>
             <div id="data_time<?php the_ID(); ?>" style="position:absolute;z-index:9;text-decoration:none;bottom:2px;right:2px;font-size:10px;color:#fff;background:#000;padding:0px 2px;-webkit-border-radius: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;border-radius: 4px;opacity:0.75;">
                    3RR:0R!
             </div>
      </div>
      <div class="postinfo">
             <div class="data_uploadedby<?php the_ID() ?>"></div>
             <div class="data_views<?php the_ID() ?>"></div>                
      </div>
      <div class="extras">
      <script type="text/javascript">
            function ytindex<?php the_ID(); echo time() ?>( data )
                    {
                    $('#data_time <?php the_ID() ?>').html( secondsToHms( data.entry[ "media$group" ][ "yt$duration" ].seconds ) );
                    $('.data_postedby<?php the_ID() ?>').html( 'by ' + data.entry[ "author" ][ 0 ].name.$t );
                    $('.data_uploadedby<?php the_ID() ?>').html( data.entry[ "title" ].$t );
                    $('.data_views<?php the_ID() ?>').html( data.entry[ "yt$statistics" ].viewCount + ' views</h3>' );
                    }
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/0000000000000?v=2&callback=ytindex<?php the_ID(); echo time() ?>"></script>
   </div>
</a>
</div>
```

Here's the result (CSS elements like thumbnail display fine, because they're handled w/ PHP, none of the other elements load): https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HYKQ.png (link b/c of SO rep)

Thanks in advance! From experience I can say most of the people on this site are awesome helpers! -Matt

Answer (score 0):

the jquery library is already included in the current versions of wordpress.  Use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to add the jquery library.
Don't just add the script to your header.php file...

Then you'll also need to use this ready function for compatibility with wordpress.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
// now you can use jQuery code here with normal $ shortcut formatting
});
```